# reactjs: how to access ref values in v15.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following piece of code that works in ReactJS v0.13.x:

```
  handleEmail: function(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
          var input_text = this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value;      
          // more code here ....
      }
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div className='dlg' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <p>
            <span className="msg">{this.state.msg}</span>
            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleEmail} ref="email" />
          </p>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

Now I've tried to convert this code to make it compatible with react v15.0.1, and I've tried something like this:

```
  handleEmail(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
          var input_text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value;;       
          // more code here ....
      }
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div className='dlg' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <p>
            <span className="msg">{this.state.msg}</span>
            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleEmail} ref="email" />
          </p>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

but it fails, I've debugged the code and found that, using the newest syntax, 'this' is null in handleEmail function.

Does anybody have any hint why worked before and not now? (and most important :) ... how to fix this?)

Comment: As a side note to the answer below, you'll commonly come across `.bind(this)` in ES6 class syntax for React, this is doing the same thing (binding the correct context of `this` to functions that are making use of it) just in a more traditional way. You could solve your issue with `this.handleEmail.bind(this)` but in the long run fat arrow `=>` functions are much more concise and convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React using ES6 classes does not auto-bind your handlers to `this` like the old-style `React.createClass()` method does.  So you need to ensure that the event handlers you use get properly bound to `this`.  Easiest way is to just write them like this:

```
handleEmail = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        var input_text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value;;       
        // more code here ....
    }
};
render() {
     return (
        <div className='dlg' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <p>
            <span className="msg">{this.state.msg}</span>
            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleEmail} ref="email" />
          </p>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Note that in your case you do not even *need* refs.  The event object has a `target` property which will be the `input` element, so you can do this too:

```
handleEmail = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        var input_text = e.target.value;;       
        // more code here ....
    }
};
render() {
     return (
        <div className='dlg' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <p>
            <span className="msg">{this.state.msg}</span>
            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleEmail} />
          </p>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Brandon, your answer definitely point me in the right direction ... although I'm not using exactly your solution (the big fat arrow notation gave me some syntax errors), I've managed to fix the code appending `.bind(this)` to `this.handleEmail`